# Cup product structure on cohomology of the real projective plane for $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space

As the question title suggests, what is the cup product structure on the cohomology of the real projective plane, for $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients?

Comment: The polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$ truncated by setting $x^n=0$ for $n \ge 3$. This is a standard example in most algebraic topology textbooks.